OpenWRT Routing to different wan port based on IP Country list
I have an OpenWRT router with 2 wan port (1 lan configured as wan).
My goal is to route the traffic based on whether the destination IP is on the list of a specific country.
So far the best method seem to use the PBR module, however, couldn't make this work reliably.
From the forum, there is this script for doing just that, but this fails to run
#!/bin/sh

TARGET_SET='wancn'
TARGET_IPSET='wancn'
TARGET_TABLE='inet fw4'
TARGET_URL="http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/cn.zone"
TARGET_DL_FILE="/etc/pbr_tmp_cn_ip_ranges"
TARGET_NFT_FILE="/etc/pbr_tmp_cn_ip_ranges.nft"
[ -z "$nft" ] && nft="$(command -v nft)"
_ret=1

if [ ! -s "$TARGET_DL_FILE" ]; then
    uclient-fetch --no-check-certificate -qO- "$TARGET_URL" 2>/dev/null > "$TARGET_DL_FILE"
fi

if [ -s "$TARGET_DL_FILE" ]; then
    if ipset -q list "$TARGET_IPSET" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        if awk -v ipset="$TARGET_IPSET" '{print "add " ipset " " $1}' "$TARGET_DL_FILE" | ipset restore -!; then
            _ret=0
        fi
    elif [ -n "$nft" ] && [ -x "$nft" ] && "$nft" list set "$TARGET_TABLE" "$TARGET_SET" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        printf "add element %s %s { " "$TARGET_TABLE" "$TARGET_SET" > "$TARGET_NFT_FILE"
        awk '{printf $1 ", "}' "$TARGET_DL_FILE" >> "$TARGET_NFT_FILE"
        printf " } " >> "$TARGET_NFT_FILE"
        if "$nft" -f "$TARGET_NFT_FILE"; then
            rm -f "$TARGET_NFT_FILE"
            _ret=0
        fi
    fi
fi

return $_ret

I've also tried configs like
config policy
        option name 'CNWAN routing'
        option dest_addr 'file:///etc/pbr_tmp_cn_ip_ranges'
        option interface 'wancn'

But couldn't get this working. At this point, I'm unsure where to look at further.
